# Java Map equivalent implementation in actionscript?

Tags: java, actionscript, dictionary, key-value

Is there any third party api which has map like implementation in actionscript ?

Answer (score 1):

The AS3Commons Collections library has a Map implementation. http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-collections/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript supports assiocative Arrays.
They are actually the Same as Maps.

```
Var Map:object =  {index1:"so,e value",index2:"other value"};
```

Comment: Are they as quick as maps ?